# Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'files') jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

verán tengo un pequeño script que de forma dinámica mediante un botón me va generando filas en una tabla, en estas filas tengo un input tipo file(para cargar fotos) y otro input text para añadir un comentario de esta foto, esto se almacena en una base de datos, hasta ahora me funciona muy bien la carga y almacenamiento, pero necesito mostrar las miniaturas de las imágenes a cargar antes de hacer el Summit (un preview de lo que se ira a cargar y guardar en la bd)

Estoy probando con un codigo que encontre, pero me da error en la propiedad files...

Este es el script que estoy probando para hacer el preview:

```
function previewMultiple(event){
        var saida = document.getElementById("foto");
        var quantos = saida.files.length;
        for(i = 0; i < quantos; i++){
            var urls = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]);
            document.getElementById("previa").innerHTML += '<img src="'+urls+'">';
        }
    }
```

el codigo js para trabajar con la generacion dinamica de filas e inputs:

```
var contador = 0;
var id_fila_seleccionada;
function agregar(){
    contador++;
    var fila ='<tr class="selected" id="fila'+contador+'" onclick="seleccionar_fila(this.id);"><td><input type="file" class="form-control im" accept="image/*"  name="imagen[]" id="imagen" onchange="previewMultiple(event)"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"  name="comentario[]"></td><td><div id="previa"></div></td></tr>';
    $("#tblDiferencial").append(fila);
}
```

Y el html:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="diferencial">
                        <h6 class="text-center">Imagenes de la Mantención</h6>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btnRegistrar">Registrar</a>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div id="tablaDiferencialDiv">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnAgregarFila">Agregar Nueva Foto</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="btnEliminarFila">Eliminar Foto</a>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="tblDiferencial">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>

                                            <th scope="col" style="width: 40%">Archivo Seleccionado</th>
                                            <th scope="col" style="width: 50% ;">Titulo/Comentario</th>
                                            </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                    </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </div>
```

Saludos a todos

Comment: ¿Leíste [esta pregunta](/q/169194)?

Comment: si me estaba pasando por alto algo, ahora si lo consegui....gracias por el link

Comment: ¿Cuál fue el caso? ¿Pregunta duplicada o _typo_?

Comment: typo y falta de llamado